# Android video stream delay: a world through somene elses webcam

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, vlc

I'm trying to stream a webcam video to my android (gingerbread 2.4.3) and I've got it all set up.  I'm streaming my webcam threw VLC with a h263 codec and a mp4 container format on a rtsp stream; my problem isn't that i cant see the video, it's that the video buffer time (8-10 seconds) is to long, I cant have this.

I was wondering if its possible to reduce the buffer time to that of a live stream?
If not then is there a way better I can display live video?